# Is there a Ldap filter for 'contains' or 'in'?

Tags: ldap

I need a Ldap query to return multiple users, and so I need it to go through a list of userIDs and search the directory.

Essentially, what I want to do is

> (|(cn=val1)(cn=val2)(cn=val3).....)

I would use just the OR filter for a few values but I need to get upto 100 values.
Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Probably a 'contains' or 'in' filter that lets me pass a list of values to check against?

Comment: Which LDAP server implementation are you querying? Some support wildcard matching

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Are there some that *don't* support it? It's required by [RFC 2254](https://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc2254), 1997.

Answer (score 9):

As the comments suggest, use a wildcard:

```
(cn=val*)
```

Comment: That's only StartsWith, not Contains or In.

Answer (score 0):

> I would use just the OR filter for a few values but I need to get up to 100 values. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

You don't need a more efficient way of doing this. Provided the `cn` attribute is indexed, this is efficient. All you're actually looking for is a different way to *express* the filter, and there isn't one.

Answer (score -2):

Create a group, cn=RequiredUsers,OU=xxx, to contain the users and then you can perform the query like this:

(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=cn=RequiredUsers,OU=xxx))

Pick a good name for the group.